# how i can save message which is sending to my email in server to database by php?

Tags: php

how i can save message which is sending to my email in server to database by php ?

i mean when you buy hosting in the internet, you have special email like john@webpower.info
i want if any body sent message to this email (john@webpower.info) from gmail, msn, special server saved messages info in database by mysql how?

no oop please

Comment: Can you restate your question?

Answer (score 1):

Let me google that for you..

http://www.jeroensmeets.net/setup-postfix-to-forward-incoming-email-to-php/

http://hostmonsterforum.com/showthread.php?436-Forwarding-Email-to-a-Script&s=0ccfa77bb25f898d95a23867e16fc89a

http://www.evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hosted email and not one on a server you control, you will need to ask your hosting provider how to do this.